# Is it possible to pass a Session variable (object) to an API as a parameter?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-web-api

I have a web page with a search criteria.

Once the user selects what he wants and inputs any keywords to search, he is re-directed to another page which shows the results of his search.

This session object contains all of the information of his search:

```
var ProjectSearchCriteria = (GBLProjectSearchCriteria) Session[GblConstants.SESSION_PROJECT_SEARCH_CRITERIA];
```

Is there a way for me to pass this object to an API?

Like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<string> getEpisodes(GBLProjectSearchCriteria psc)
{
     var ProjectSearchResult = new ProjectSearchResultController();
     var GBLProjectSearchResultListData = ProjectSearchResult.GetProjectSearchResultList(psc);
     return (from GBLProjectSearchResult item 
             in GBLProjectSearchResultListData
             select item.Title).ToList();
}
```

The reason why I want to do this is because the search criteria is massive and it already exists so I don't want the API to have 38032823 parameters.

Is this even possible? How would I do it? Any alternatives?

Comment: What is the problem with passing the object to the API? You just do `getEpisodes(ProjectSearchCriteria)` and you should be good...

Comment: Web APIs usually should be designed as `stateless`, so not having session data. Besides this, what is wrong with simply accessing the `Session` variable inside your method? Or can you only access this variable from where ever you call your Web API? In this case you can only pass your complex object to the API when you use the verb `PUT` or `POST` and send the object as the request content.

Comment: Badri's answer should suffice, why don't you mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API binds parameters from either URI, query string, etc. or the request body. If you want to bind from any thing else, especially outside of the request message, you can create your own parameter binding. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx). The blog post creates a parameter binding for type `IPrincipal` but you can do something similar for `GBLProjectSearchCriteria'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
getEpisodes((GBLProjectSearchCriteria) Session[GblConstants.SESSION_PROJECT_SEARCH_CRITERIA]);
```

One obvious question I have is, since you know the datatype already, and are type-casting to it, why are you using var?

```
var ProjectSearchCriteria = (GBLProjectSearchCriteria) ....
```

Doesn't this make more sense?

```
GBLProjectSearchCriteria  ProjectSearchCriteria = (GBLProjectSearchCriteria) ....
```

Comment: `var` is often used just as a shortcut to prevent duplication when its obvious what it is. Its a matter of preference really whether to use var but I personally find the latter to be much harder to read.

Comment: Some people use "var" by default unless they want to emphasize the type in order to increase understanding of the code.  see http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=61

Comment: developerwjk, you mean putting ((GBLProjectSearchCriteria) Session[GblConstants.SESSION_PROJECT_SEARCH_CRITERIA]) on the URL? i tried that and it didnt work.

Comment: I think you are really missing the point of the question and do not understand the context. He is asking about the ASP.NET Web API framework, not simple code to call a method. The Web API framework maps HTTP requests to methods in your code, so he is not calling this method in his code but rather calling an URI mapped to his method - and that one can't accept a complex parameter when using the GET verb.

Comment: @user1908061: That makes a lot more sense. The OP mainly mentions API in the question rather than Web API. I missed the tags (I rarely look at them I must admit) so assumed it was a normal API.